# Deserializing generic java object returns LinkedTreeMap

Tags: java, json, generics, gson

I have a generic Java `Message` object that's represented by the following json string:

```
{
  "type": "Example",
  "processTime": 3.4,
  "payload": 
   {
    "id": "someString",
    "type": "anotherString",
    "message": "yetAnotherString"
  }
}
```

The Java `Message` object is generic.  I also have an object called `Event`. When trying to convert the json into a `Message<Event>` object using gson, a `Message` object is returned with the correct json values, but the nested generic object is somehow returned as a "LinkedTreeMap" object instead of an `Event` object. I know this has something to do with type erasure, but I still can't seem to figure out how to return a `Message<Event>` from the json.

This is my `main()`:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //The json string to convert into a "Message<Event>" object
        String jsonString = "{\"type\":\"Example\",\"processTime\":3.4,\"payload\":{\"id\":\"someString\",\"type\":\"anotherString\",\"message\":\"yetAnotherString\"}}";

        Message<Event> message = new Message<Event>(); 

        message = message.convertJsonToObject(jsonString, Event.class);

        System.out.println(message.getClass().getName()); //returns as a "Message" class -- as expected
        System.out.println(message.getPayload().getClass().getName()); //returns as a "LinkedTreeMap" instead of an "Event" object

    }
}
```

`Message` class:

```
public class Message<T> {

    private String type;

    private double processTime;

    private T payload;

    public Message(String type, double processTime, T payload) {
        this.type = type;
        this.processTime = processTime;
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    public Message() {
        type = null;
        processTime = 0;
        payload = null;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public double getProcessTime() {
        return processTime;
    }

    public void setProcessTime(double processTime) {
        this.processTime = processTime;
    }

    public T getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }

    public void setPayload(T payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    public Message<T> convertJsonToObject(String jsonString, Class<T> classType) {

        GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
        Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Message<T>>() {}.getType();
        Message<T> myMessage = gson.create().fromJson(jsonString, collectionType);

        return myMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new Gson().toJson(this);
    }
}
```

`Event` class:

```
public class Event {

    private String id;

    private String type;

    private String message;

    public Event(String id, String type, String message) {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new Gson().toJson(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types. You need a TypeToken<Message<Event>>. The whole point of the type token is to capture the actual generic type: Event. Also, please, make the convertJsonToObject method static. You shouldn't have to crete a Message in order to deserialize JSON to another Message.

Comment: Yup - unless you tell GSON your generic types it won’t know what they are. And for `Object` it will deserialise into a `Map` that preserves the order of the elements in the JSON.